# Coherence client - not store data

Tags: oracle-coherence

How do I stop the Coherence client node storing data. Ie to connect to the cluster, GET data and then disconnect, without the cluster trying to pass data to the node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the client with the following jvm flag:

```
-Dtangosol.coherence.distributed.localstorage=false
```

I hope you are connecting to cluster as an extend client, but not like a regular member.

Comment: Thanks for the response, how do I ensure that I connect as an extended client? I thought the command above would ensure that?

Comment: Read this- http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH34UG/Configuring+and+Using+Coherence+Extend and go for ExtendTCPProxy. The main idea behind telling you to connect via Extend Client, is to make sure that if the client continuously connects and disconnects from the cluster, the integrity of the cluster is not impacted.